# Is user consent required for recording request URL and timestamp?

Tags: logging, web-applications, profiling, server-side

I would like my Web application to record the URL and timestamp of every request it serves + the time it took to render the page on the server side. I need this data for code profiling and very simple analytics (which routes are accessed how often, how are parameters used, how many requests do we have in general etc.). **No user-related data** (like e.g. IP address) is recorded, but the request URLs may contain information entered to text fields (e.g. search queries).

Would this possibly be expected to require user consent anywhere?